# AWS API Gateway only allows the first element of the form data and ignores the rest

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, urlencode, jsonpath

I have been trying to push data into AWS SQS using AWS API Gateway, the data I send is in the form of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

And it looks somewhat like this:

```
fruits[]: apple
fruits[]: mango
fruits[]: banana
season: summer
```

Now when I poll the data from AWS SQS, I see only `fruits[]=apple` has been stored and all others are ignored.

This is my current mapping template to push in SQS:

```
Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$input.body
```

Looks like it has multiple `$input.body` but if that is the case then its kinda impossible to capture random data coming in.

I am new to AWS API Gateway, thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of research and stuff, I was able to decipher this mystery.

the value of `$input.body` is:

`fruits[]=apple&fruits[]=mango&fruits[]=banana&season=summer`

Now only `MessageBody` is pushed in SQS, so according to my template, the resulting query string which was forming, was:

```
Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=fruits[]=apple&fruits[]=mango&fruits[]=banana&season=summer
```

only `fruits[]=apple` is falling under `MessageBody` and all other becomes separate query objects and hence were ignored.

I just had to tweak the template to:

```
Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$util.urlEncode($input.body)
```

So the resulting query string does not include any more `&` or `=` and every thing falls under `MessageBody`

Edits are welcomed

Answer (score -1):

try this

**Request:**

```
POST apigateway/stage/resource?query=test
{
  "season": "summer",
  "list": [apple,mango,banana]
}
```

**Mapping:**

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "query": "$input.params('query')",
  "id": "$inputRoot.season",
  "list": $inputRoot.list
}
```

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-mapping-templates-to-handle-changes-in-your-back-end-apis/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/example-photos.html